# Exceptions in Code Activities Used in CRM Workflows

Tags: dynamics-crm, workflow, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-365

I have a custom code activity that is being run as part of a background workflow on a large number of records that are entered into the Dynamics 365 CRM as part of an integration.

As I cannot control the quality of the data that is being pushed into the CRM, there are certain situations where I want to explicitly throw an exception so that the error message is displayed in the system job record screen.

What we've found is that after a certain number of these legitimate exceptions are thrown, all remaining workflows of this type are postponed with the error:

> This operation has been postponed because it failed for more than 50 times in 30 minutes

Is there a setting where I can control this threshold or turn it off?

If not, what approach should I take when workflows will legitimately throw exceptions as part of their process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This trap is for damage control (Async services load) to avoid any further damage from customization / implementation by another shared tenant in same scale group of CRM online.

You can reach out to MS support for better resolution. AFAIK you cannot override this behavior.

> Name: AsyncOperationPostponed Hex: 80040328 Number: -2147220696
>   This operation has been postponed because it failed for more than {0} times in {1} minutes

[Error code reference](http://dyn365apps.com/2017/02/09/quick-reference-dynamics-365-web-service-error-codes/)

Alternate choice: You can write in Plugin Trace logs using `ITracingService` without throwing exception.

Comment: Adding to that, you could catch the exception in code, flag the record with a new `hasError` field (or something like that) and even add an `errorMessage` field and populate the exception into it. This way you have all the data you need right on the record where you can easily filter, and you avoid having the platform shut you down due to excessive exceptions.